# to delete the remaining line from a particular word using shell script

Tags: shell

This is the output for me but i want only address.So that i want to remove from with to last of the line.Give me some code to remove.

> 347-6450 Roberts St with 391 links.
>
> 175 E. Broadway Suite 208 with 1 links.
>
> 412 Summerhill Ave with 34 links.
>
> 50 Empringham Drive with 32 links.
>
> 121 Willowdale Ave Suite 202 with 355 links.
>
> 200 Dufferin Street with 296 links.
>
> 650 West Georgia Street Suite 1010 with 857 links.
>
> 1726 Dolphin Ave Suite 203 with 432 links.

I want to delete the remaining line from the particular word "with"

Expected Output:

> 347-6450 Roberts St
>
> 175 E. Broadway Suite 208
>
> 412 Summerhill Ave
>
> 50 Empringham Drive
>
> 121 Willowdale Ave Suite 202
>
> 200 Dufferin Street
>
> 650 West Georgia Street Suite 1010
>
> 1726 Dolphin Ave Suite 203

Comment: yes i searched for so much time then only i just make the question in this

Comment: You got the correct answer this time.  Next time, provide others with your own solution (even if it doesn't work) and don't ask others to just solve your problem.

Comment: Sure i will provide others with my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat input.txt | sed 's/with.*$//'`

sed is a program to do simple text operations. `s/with.*$//` replaces with and following characters (`.*`) til the end of line (`$`) with empty string.

More info about sed, you can read it [here](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/04/sed-explained-part-1/).

Comment: Thank you sooooo much impressive